# Boundary value problem $\frac{d}{dt} \bigl( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert}\bigr) = 0$ with $c(t_0) = x_0, c(t_1) = x_1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Consider an interval $I = [t_0,t_1]$ and a finite dimensional Banach space $X$. Let further be $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times X \times X$ and let  $V \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{1}(I,X)$ be the set of all curves $c:I \rightarrow X$ where $(t,c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is contained in $U$ for all $t$. Let further be
>
> $$\lvert\lvert c \rvert\rvert_{\mathcal{C}^1(I)} := \sup_{t \in I} \lvert\lvert c(t) \rvert\rvert_X + \sup_{t \in I}\lvert\lvert c^\prime(t) \rvert\rvert_X.$$
>
> Solve the boundary value problem
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert}\bigg) = 0$$
>
> with $c(t_0) = x_0, c(t_1) = x_1$. Remark: The norm of in $\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert$ is the one given above.

I am new to differential equations, so here are my thoughts: I tried to take the line $c$ through $x_0$ and $x_1$, i.e.:

$$c(t) := x_0 + \frac{t-t_0}{t_1-t_0} \cdot (x_1-x_0).$$

While this fullfills the boundary conditions $c(t_0) = x_0$ and $c(t_1) = x_1$, its derivative is not equal to zero. However, how should a solution to this problem look, I mean derivative zero would mean that the solution would have to be constant, but how should this be possible if $x_1 \ne x_2$? Could you please help me?

Comment: What norm is $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ in $\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert}\bigg) = 0$?

Comment: The norm given above, I'll make an edit.

Comment: As you put it now, the norm is a constant and can be removed from the equation, which then reduces to $c''=0$. If it were $\|c'(t)\|_X$, then it becomes a statement about curvature, which might still lead to the same result, but with variable parametrization.

Comment: Ah now I see. Sorry, but I got confused. Thanks for your help.